# Mre and mRe tags

Tags: feature-request

Writing `[mre]` in comments creates "[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" (text and link). Very useful. But I and others often feel compelled to additionally point out why it isn't one. Can we get `[Mre]` turned into  "[**minimal** reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" (and likewise for r and perhaps also e)?

Comment: I'm not sure users are going to notice that one of the words is bolded, or what that's supposed to mean.

Comment: @cigien In one of your most recent comments you used *italic*, which is *less* noticeable. Why did you bother doing that if you think people don't notice?

Comment: I'm not claiming that emphasis is *never* useful. I'm just saying that in this case, a user who has failed to provide an MRE probably needs to read the entire contents of the link. It's not clear to me that emphasizing up front exactly how the user has failed to provide an MRE is going to be particularly useful. Additionally, for a feature-request, you need to account for the dev time involved to implement it, and at least currently, the dev team has much more pressing concerns IMO. This shouldn't be an issue for you to do when writing a comment; there are a number of userscripts that'll help.

Comment: @cigien In cases where I'd use this, e.g., when they have a reproducible example but it's just not minimal, then I disagree that they need to read the entire page. And I think it could help make them actually read the part I want them to read. I can only speak for myself, but if someone points me to some page saying "read this", I'm much less motivated to actually do it and try to figure out what part is relevant than when they point it out. Especially when I start reading and notice it all appears to be irrelevant. I might just stop reading then, annoyed that they wasted my time.

Comment: Be more useful for me if you could use a shortcut as the url in a link with your own text, e.g. `Take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](mre).` Then you could also mess with the formatting if that is what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the current form of `[mre]` shortcut and additionally **repeat the word** you want to focus on. E.g. you could write

> Please note, that [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) implies **minimal**, but your code doesn't look so.

I find that way more informative than silently bold a word in the link text.

---

Also, supporting things like `[mRe]` would imply that `[mre]` shortcut will **always contain** a "reproducible" word in its expansion. However, not many years ago it was `[mcve]` shortcut instead, and it was expanded to "minimal complete verifiable example". I still use `[mcve]`, but now its **expansion has been changed** to be the same as of `[mre]` ("minimal reproducible example"). Would they support e.g. `[mcVe]` shortcut before, its specifics (bolded word "verifiable") would be completely lost during the shortcut transformation.

That is, I find better to think about `[mre]` (and `[mcve]`) as

> **some text** corresponding to 'that example', and that text links to **some useful resource**.

and do not rely on specific wording in its expansion.